# Zenity - no scroll bar with long text

Tags: bash, scrollbar, zenity

I try to use zenity as a GUI for my bash script. At first step I want to show a user agreement which is quite long text but there is no scroll bar so the user could scroll down the text.

I use:

```
 LICENSE_TEXT=`cat license.txt`
zenity --question --title "question dialog" --text="$LICENSE_TEXT"
```

I have also tried:

```
 LICENSE_TEXT=`cat license.txt`
zenity --question --title "question dialog" --filename=license.txt
```

But it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 3):

OK, found the solution:

```
FILE=`dirname $0`/license.txt

zenity --text-info \
   --title="License" \
   --filename=$FILE \
   --checkbox="I read and accept the terms."
```